# Quais são os tipos de cascade no JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, modelagem, jpa-2.0, modelo-relacional

Estou buscando informações dos tipos de cascade que existem e como eles funcionam na modelagem relacional com JPA. Os tipos que encontrei explicações foram:

- **NONE** = Não faz nada com o objeto (padrão)
- **MERGE** = Atualiza filhos quando atualiza o pai, somente se já estiver persisitido
- **PERSIST** = Salva o filho quando salva o pai
- **REFRESH** = Salva o pai e mantém o filho sem alterar
- **REMOVE** = Remove o filho quando remove o pai e vice-versa
- **ALL** = Executa todas as operações de cascade

Tenhos as seguintes dúvidas:

1. Está correta a explicação de funcionamento desses tipos de `cascade`?
2. Mapeamento com **`mappedBy`** deve-se colocar o `cascade` apenas no objeto pai?
3. Encontrei referências de `cascade` **DETACH** e **LOCK**, como eles funcionam?

Comment: This tutorial was helpful to me, it may help in your case. https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Existem seis tipos de cascades (CascadeType) na especificação do [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html). São eles:

- **ALL** = Realiza todas as operações em cascata
- **DETACH** = Realiza a operação detach em cascata
- **MERGE** = Realiza a operação merge em cascata
- **PERSIST** = Realiza a operação persist em cascata
- **REFRESH** = Realiza a operação refresh em cascata
- **REMOVE** = Realiza a operação remove em cascata

Realizar operações em cascata só faz sentido em relacionamentos Pai - Filho (a transição do estado da entidade Pai sendo realizada em cascata na entidade Filho). Por mais que seja permitido mapear o cascade no sentido inverso (Filho - Pai) não é muito útil e não pode ser considerado uma boa prática.

> 1. Está correta a explicação de funcionamento desses tipos de cascade?

- Quando o **MERGE** é executado, ele também persiste os filhos caso eles ainda não tenham sido persistidos.
- **REFRESH** não salva, mas atualiza a entidade com as informações do banco.

> 2. Mapeamento com mappedBy deve-se colocar o cascade apenas no objeto pai?

- É boa prática que as operações em cascata sejam feitas de pai para filho, e não o contrário, apesar de ser válido.

> 3. Encontrei referências de cascade DETACH e LOCK, como eles funcionam?

- Cascade **DETACH** faz com que a operação detach, quando executada no pai, também seja executada no filho. Dizemos que uma entidade é detached quando ela não está sendo gerenciada pelo EntityManager. Isso acontece quando exectamos o método detach(entidade) do EntityManager, quando a transação é comitada ou dá rollback.
- Cascade **LOCK** não faz parte do JPA mas sim do Hibernate. Basicamente quando você adquirir um lock na entidade pai, essa operação será realizada também nos filhos.